How to call UniswapV2 Router addLiquidityETH function from solidity smart contract?
i'm trying to add liquidity in uniswap v2 router from a solidity smart contract, but it seems to fail even though the allowance have been given.
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "./IUniswapV2Router01.sol";
import "./IERC20.sol"; // Import ERC20 interface if needed

contract MyContract {
    IUniswapV2Router01 public uniswapRouter;
    address public tokenAddress;
    
    constructor(address _router, address _tokenAddress) {
        uniswapRouter = IUniswapV2Router01(_router);
        tokenAddress = _tokenAddress;
    }
    
    function addLiquidityETH(uint amountTokenDesired, uint amountTokenMin, uint amountETHMin, uint deadline) external payable {
        // Approve the router to spend the token on behalf of this contract
        IERC20 token = IERC20(tokenAddress);
        token.approve(address(uniswapRouter), amountTokenDesired);
        
        // Call addLiquidityETH function
        uniswapRouter.addLiquidityETH{value: msg.value}(
            tokenAddress,
            amountTokenDesired,
            amountTokenMin,
            amountETHMin,
            address(this),
            deadline
        );
    }
}

Can someone explain me what's the mistake i'm doing ? Or could help me with the actual solidity code to call addLiquidityETH function in uniswapv2router.

Before adding liquidity to a Uniswap pool, the tokens that are intended to be added as liquidity must first be sent to the contract that will handle the liquidity addition. That means you have to call transferFrom or for better error handling call safeTransferFrom
Openzeppelin has SafeERC20. to implement this in your contract:
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol";

// inside contract
IERC20 token1 = IERC20(tokenAddress1);
IERC20 token2 = IERC20(tokenAddress2);

token1.safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amountOfToken1);
token2.safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amountOfToken2);

